# How to multiply the numbers in csv file per line and add together

Tags: perl

I need a way to take the numbers in one line in my .csv file and multiply them together, and then add the products from each line together to get just one number. My .csv file looks something like:

> 1,1
>      2,3
>      3,4

I know the answer should be 19, but I'm not sure how exactly to program it in Perl. I have both numbers split into different variables by:

> ($x,$y) = split (/,/, $line)

I've already read the file in and all that, I just need help with this one part of my code.
If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naive solution could look like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

my $total;
open(my $fh, '<', "temp.csv");

while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
   my ($x, $y) = split(',', $line);
   $total += ($x * $y);
}

print "Total is: $total\n";
```

Comment: $total += ($x * $y); was just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In short form

```
perl -F, -anE'$s+=$F[0]*$F[1]}{say$s'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $sum = 0;

open my $csv, '<', $filename or die $!;

while(my $line = <$csv>) {
    my $prod = 1;
    $prod *= $_ for split ',', $line;
    $sum += $prod;
}
```